# Complex Function in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an expression

((cos(-0.2 * pi)*(y-1) - (sin(-0.2 * pi)*x))) = 0.2 * (abs( sin((10*pi*(sin(-0.2 * pi) * (y - 1) + cos(-0.2 * pi) * x))^1)))^6

that I want to draw in a ggplot with geom_point plotted points.
The function will look similar to this image when plotted:
[image: Plotted Function]

The problem with the function is probably the overlapping values. I have tried to solve it by using a contour plot as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915399/r-ggplot2-how-do-i-plot-an-implicit-function-contour-line-at-just-one-level). This solution produced the following result: 
[image: Plotted Function with Contour Plot]

However, this plot seems imprecise, so I would like to find a better solution for plotting this kind of function in R with ggplot.

Comment: I am not trying to draw the line with geom_point. I have a set of points that I plot with geom_point _and_ then I also want a line that is based on an expression. The line should not depend on the points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the idea of the contour plot, you only have to increase the resolution in x and y.
Here you will find a script with your function. The lower the value of `resolution` here, the higher the precision. Be careful not to use a too high value that would create a very long calculation...
It starts to be good with 0.05:

```
library(ggplot2)
resolution <- 0.005
xy <- expand.grid(x = seq(0, 1, resolution), y = seq(0, 1, resolution))
z <- apply(xy, 1, function(xy) {
  x <- xy[1]
  y <- xy[2]
  0.2 * (abs( sin((10*pi*(sin(-0.2 * pi) * (y - 1) + cos(-0.2 * pi) * x))^1)))^6 - 
  ((cos(-0.2 * pi)*(y-1) - (sin(-0.2 * pi)*x)))
})

xyz <- data.frame(xy, z)

ggplot() +
geom_contour(data=xyz,
             aes(x=x,y=y,z=z),breaks=0,
             colour="black")
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! I cannot upvote because of my reputation, but i would have done it if I could.